# Найти наибольшее из двух действительных чисел, используя переключатель

Tags: c++

```
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
 
// Найти наибольшее из двух действительных чисел, используя переключатель.
int main(){
 
SetConsoleCP(65001);
SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
 
float a = 0, b = 0;
cin >> a >> b;
bool result;
 
if (a > b){
    result = true;
}
else{
    result = false;
}
 
switch (result)
{
case true:
    cout << "A > b" << endl;
    break;
 
default:
cout << "B > A" << endl;
    break;
}
 
 
 
 system("pause");
}
```

Всем привет! Надо написать программу которая бы находила наибольшее из двух действительных чисел (float), используя переключатель switch.

Вот моя версия программы но надо сделать ее как то без if. Буду очень благодарен всем кто поможет

Comment: Ответом оформлять не вижу смысла. Посмотрите внимательно, что делает Ваш ```if```  Он присваивает значение булевой переменной ```result``` Но результат выполнения ```(a > b)``` является логическим значением, поэтому вполне можно написать ```result = (a > b);```

Comment: Ну просто напишите `switch (A > B)`. И заодно подумайте, что будет, если вдруг `A==B` :)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: просто нужна одна строчка:  cout << ((a > b) ? " a > b" : "a <= b");

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, надо именно со switch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в swith не правильно передавали переменную.

```
int main()
{
    float a = 0, b = 0;
    std::cin >> a >> b;

    switch (a>b)
    {
    case true:
        std::cout << "A > b" << std::endl;
        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "B > A" << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Да, уже понял, спасибо)